# website cannot be started another website may be using the same port

Tags: asp.net, iis

Trying to set up a default website in IIS. When trying to start the website I get the error message: "website cannot be started another website may be using the same port."

I don't see any other bindings on port 80 in IIS. Is there a way to determine what else might be using the port on the machine?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ran across an issue like this when I was setting up a new web site on port 80.  Of course, the Default Web Site instance is also on port 80, and conflicts.  I thought I solved this by going to "Edit Bindings" and changing the "Default Web Site's" port to 81 and leaving my new site on 80. I still could not start my new site.

**I had to delete and re-create my new web site, then I could start it.**

It's like it still thought "Default Web Site" was on 80, even though it wasn't.  Even an `iisreset`, a recycle of my new site's app pool and web site all did not work.  Maybe if I had restarted the site/app pool of the "Default Web Site", maybe that would've worked, too, but didn't try it - just deleted/re-created my new site.  But that was enough to break through the "Default Web Site" keeping a hold of that port!

Comment: Over 2 hours spent on this issue, and this was the fix for me. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 17):

I also received this error, but it was not because of multiple sites (my installation of IIS only had a single site with a single binding).

Running `netstat -ano` showed nothing listening on port `8624`.

The problem was that a [URL Reservation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/about-url-reservations-and-registration-ssrs-configuration-manager) was generated previously for a different web server. I was able to query the URL ACLs with the following command in PowerShell as administrator:

```
netsh http show urlacl
```

To remove it, enter the following (replace the last argument with the reserved URL from the `show urlacl` query):

```
netsh http delete urlacl http://*:8624/
```

Comment: This resolved my issue, even though it was http not https.  urlacl was reporting http://

Comment: I still don't know what happened here but thank you for sharing this - this fixed the issue for me as well. 

Answer (score 6):

or more specifically, go to cmd and type in :

netstat -aon | find ":80"

Answer (score 2):

Go to Cmd, then type netstat -a 
Look for local address or local port for 80, or http

Comment: FYI 'netstat -all' gave me the help output. 'netstat -a' was the one i needed.

Comment: This is also the long way to go, since this report is generally cluttered up, and there's *usually* not very many sites. Can just as easily, and directly, check in IIS > click Edit Bindings of each site to see their assigned port. It is there you'd want to change it, too, if it is also port 80 - kills 2 birds with one stone.

Answer (score 2):

After reboot of a system the "Windows Sync Share" service was occupying port 80 and 443.  This service needed to be stopped allowing the default website on 80 to start.  Changing the "Windows Sync Share" service from "automatic" to "disabled" prevented this from reoccurring.

Comment: Wow that was the issue I had.   Basically netstat for port 80 is a red hearing.  IIS binds that port and it will always show as in use.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.  In my case there was only one site.  Somehow the install of a certificate created a second https binding?!  Deleting one of the bindings solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Found that I had to bind my application in https mode, a cert is installed on my PC which defaults to 443 port when binding.

Answer (score -1):

to check which web is using port
**netstat -ano**

to check url name -
**netstat -aon | find ":80"**

using url name delete binding with port
**netsh http delete urlacl http://*:80/**

check again

restart server if impact is not visible.

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers, unless you want to share new insights. If this is the case here, please add some further explanation such that others can learn from your answer